# How do I extract a variable from another class

Tags: java, getter-setter

I'm currently creating a banking application. The idea of this is to have a user enter their name, the code checks to see if a file exists with that name (john.txt for example). If it exists, the user will be prompted to deposit/withdraw/check balance/quit from their bank and their new updated balance is saved to this txt file. If the user doesn't exist it creates a txt file with the balance 0 and the user can do the same processes onto their bank. I have this part all working fine.

The issue I'm having lies in the next step. I now want to create a list of transactions that user has completed and add these to another txt file (johnTransactions.txt for example). The way I've grabbed the user name is from a method in a Reader class I made using a scanner. I can't figure out how to extract/move (not sure of the correct term here) this name variable to my Bank class, where I will use it to write my list of transactions to the file name+"transactions.txt".

In my runner class I can use account.getName to print out John but when I do account.getName in my bank class it is coming back as null. I suspect the issue lies somewhere in the order that my code is running but I can't seem to figure out the issue. I've attached some code below of my bank/account/runner class but please could anyone help me to understand why getName in account is returning null but getName in runner returns the correct name.

Bank

```
public class Bank {
    Account account = new Account();
    ScannerClass scanner = new ScannerClass();
    DateManager dateManager = new DateManager();
    List<Transaction> transactions = account.getTransactions();

public double ManageBank(double balance) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int userChoice;

    boolean quit = false;

    do {

        userChoice = scanner.InitialChoiceScanner();

        double amount;
        String name = account.getName();
        switch (userChoice) {

        case 1:

            amount = scanner.DepositScanner();
            balance = account.Deposit(balance, amount);
            System.out.print("Your new balance is: " + balance);

            String depositFullDate = dateManager.getDateAsString();
            Transaction depositTransaction = new Transaction("Depsoit", depositFullDate, amount);
            transactions.add(depositTransaction);

            break;

        case 2:

            amount = scanner.WithdrawScanner();
            balance = account.Withdraw(balance, amount);
            System.out.print("Your new balance is: " + balance);

            String withdrawFullDate = dateManager.getDateAsString();
            Transaction withdrawTransaction = new Transaction("Withdraw", withdrawFullDate, amount);
            transactions.add(withdrawTransaction);

            break;

        case 3:

            System.out.print("Your current balance is: " + balance);

            break;

        case 0:

            quit = true;

            break;

        default:

            System.out.println("Please select a valid choice;");

            break;

        }

        System.out.println();

    } while (!quit);

    account.setTransactions(transactions);
    System.out.println("This is the name" + name);
    System.out.println("Thankyou for using the banking service!");

    return balance;
}
```

Account

```
public class Account {

private String name;
private Double balance;
private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();



public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
    return transactions;
}

public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
    this.transactions = transactions;
}

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Reader reader = new Reader();
Writer writer = new Writer();



public Account(String name, double balance) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
}

public Account() {
    
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    balance = this.balance;
}

public double Deposit(double balance, double amount) {
    balance = balance + amount;
    return balance;
}

public double Withdraw(double balance, double amount) {
    balance = balance - amount;
    return balance;
}

public void ManageAccount(String name) {
    Bank bank = new Bank();
    try {
        File myObj = new File(name + ".txt");
        
        if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
            File myTransactionObj = new File(name + "Transactions.txt");
            myTransactionObj.createNewFile();
            // If File doesn't exist creates name.txt with 0 balance
            writer.SingleLineWriter(name, "0");
        } else {
            setName(name);
            String line = reader.SingleLineRead(name);

            double balance = Double.parseDouble(line);
            
            double newBalance = bank.ManageBank(balance);

            writer.BalanceAppender(newBalance, name);
            
            

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
}
```

Runner

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account();
        ScannerClass scanner = new ScannerClass();

        String name=scanner.NameScanner();
        account.ManageAccount(name);






    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created account object, but haven't set name

```
Account account = new Account();
```

as a result `account.getName()` is null, you need to set `account.setName()` before trying to access it by getter

You need to relook into `ManageAccount` method

Comment: So the instance of account in my Bank class is just empty because I've just made it at the top and a name hasn't been set yet. I thought as I'd used the setName in ManageAccount I can access the name using getName elsewhere. It's returning the right thing in the runner class and I have the exact same line of code you posted in there too. Is it just an issue in the order that my code is running then how would I go about changing it as I'm completely stumped.

Comment: `It's returning the right thing in the runner class` what do you mean by this, there are print statements or not getting name in Runner

Comment: Apologies I should be more clear. I've added this.
    String findName = account.getName();
    System.out.println("this is the name"+findName);
It returns the name that I've inputted in the case I mentioned above John.

Comment: `setName(name);` is this line compiling?

Comment: Yeah it compiles fine. I can access it in other places using account.getName() but it isn't working in the bank class in my method where I need it.